# Как сделать автоматически дату на сейчас при создании объекта модели?

Tags: model, ruby-on-rails, scaffolding, события

Есть модель, сгенерированная через **`scaffolding`**, куда вписать `creation_date = Time.now`, чтобы **`creation_date`** был равен дате создания объекта?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У модели уже есть свойство `created_at`. Его и используйте.

Comment: могу добавить, вы не мыслите "rails-way", не пишите пожалуйста на рельсах

Comment: @pavelbel, я штоле?

Comment: Вспомнил про него только сейчас, просто последний раз с рельсами имел дело около гола назад, читая railstutotial :D.
Но за быстрый ответ - спасибо.

Comment: 2debian да не ты, я топикстартеру писал, не хотелось плодить ответы

Comment: @pavelbel, ну может, тогда укажите мне "Way to Rails-Way"? :D

Comment: хехе)) вам указали уже.. читайте исходники рельсов и будет вам rails-way. я так понимаю, вы уже издеваетесь, тем не менее

Comment: Тогда никогда не начинайте изучать новые ЯП... Вы же не сразу о них всё узнаёте и мыслите в начале не как их разработчики.

Comment: Не свойство, а метод же. Вы ООП или где (:

Comment: Метод??? А Вы в институте ООП проходили?

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите schema.rb
В ней вся структура базы данных проекта (: